# Rspec: testing assignment of instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using Rspec with Factory Girl. Trying to check out what data is being assigned in my controller (and test against it).  Every post I've read says I should be able to get something out of assigns() but it keeps returning nill

Controller

```
def index
 @stickies = Sticky.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Spec

```
it "should assign stickies" do
  foo = assigns(:stickies)
  puts "foo = #{foo}"
end
```

Output

```
foo =
```

Am I using the wrong syntax? Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You have to invoke the action first

```
describe StickiesController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "should assign stickies" do
      get :index
      assigns(:stickies).should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One of my more bone-headed moves.  Thanks, David. ;)

Comment: There is no such thing as a bone-headed move.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using the rspec > 2.99 you can use:

`expect(assigns(:stickies)).not_to be_nil`