# Rspec + OAuth: Having trouble signing in from within a test (omniauth mock)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

I'm testing a controller in my app which should render one view for users who've given over their info and requested access ("signed in guests") and another view for the rest of the world (anonymous users). I'm using OmniAuth and Rolify.

Test goes like this:

```
context 'signed in guests' do
   before do
     guest = create(:user,:guest)
     OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google] = {
          uid: guest.uid
     }
     session[:user_id] = guest.id
   end
   it "shows the Please Wait for Confirmation view" do
     puts "Rspec says Current User: #{@current_user.inspect}"
     get :index
     response.should render_template :pending_authorization
   end
  end
```

User factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do
  name "MyString"
  email "MyString"
  provider "MyString"
  uid "MyString"

  trait :admin do
    after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:admin)}
  end

  trait :guest do
    after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:guest)}
  end

  trait :authorized_user do
    after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:user)}
  end

end
```

end

However, when I run this, my puts actually gives me this:

```
 Rspec says Current User: nil
```

So... why is the current user nil even though I create it with the omniauth mock?

**Edit:** current_user comes from my application helper, if that helps any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using the before block to edit the session directly, have you considered using it to actually sign in the user the way they would via the site? You can put it in a helper/shared_context and then run it before any specs that need a logged in user. I use `current_user` with Sinatra, but it's a helper I write that accesses the underlying session.

Comment: That's a great idea, only I have no clue how to do it. I use OmniAuth for signing in, so it's a very opaque process for me. I've searched all over the place how to sign in users via tests. Right now I have it working in an integration test where Capybara physically clicks the Log In button, but this controller test doesn't have Capybara (nor would its helper), so I'm not sure how to do this... Any ideas? Also, thanks for replying to this complex q.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I've come to the decision to focus on integration tests instead of controller tests, partly because it's so difficult to write these kind of things properly due to the lack of _easy_ session support in the testing tools, and partly because the controller is only one step away from the rendered site anyway. Where did you get the `current_user` bit from? Sounds like a Warden/Devise helper. If so, this may help https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Comment: Nope, it's not Devise - I'm only using OmniAuth. It's from the RailsApps project, which I've used as a template. So... no way to make this work, you say?

Comment: Having read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720135/rspec-testing-assignment-of-instance-variable) it's possible the variable isn't assigned until after the `get` action is called.

Comment: Oh man, that had me hoping! But it didn't work. :( I swapped the lines around (put the get first, then the puts with @current.user), still got nil in the puts. What's weird is that the test does pass! Any other ideas? Should I not worry about it and just assume it's fine because the test somehow does pass? Thank you for dedicating time for this on Christmas!

Comment: Are you able to access any other instance variables within that example's context? Maybe the spec passes because the rendering works, but for some reason you're not able to access the var in the example's context? Don't worry about it being Christmas, I'm a buddhist :)

Comment: Because the test passes, I decided to just give it a go in real life (try it out using the browser), and it actually doesn't work. In real life, newly created users don't aren't even assigned the role of guests. I'd be happy to check other instance variables, but which ones would you suggest I check?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21643/discussion-between-ezuk-and-iain)