# RSpec controller test + OmniAuth = bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

This is a generalized version of a [more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013366/rspec-oauth-having-trouble-signing-in-from-within-a-test-omniauth-mock#comment19350754_14013366) question I've had. Basically, I have a project that uses OmniAuth + rolify, and I'm trying to create controller tests (not integration/feature tests, but specifically testing the controller).

The problem is that this controller has conditional logic depending on the type of user logged in. Trying to log a mock user in via OmniAuth from inside a controller test is turning out to be a bit of a nightmare.

Is this because I'm a noob who doesn't know how to do this, or because trying to use OmniAuth mocks from within controller tests is just a bad idea?

Any tips/pointers would be most appreciated. I'm not using Devise, just OmniAuth and rolify.

Comment: Ever figure out anything about this? I have a similar situation. My controller behaves differently for different kinds of users. I don't want to *test* Omniauth there. I just want the current_user to be properly set to my test user.