# How do I write functional test for this

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am pretty new to rspec. How do I write functional test for following piece of code.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @title = "Log in to Mint"
     @msg = session[:msg]
     session[:msg] = nil
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
describe FooController do

  describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns 'Log in to Mint' to @title" do
      get :new
      assigns(:title).should == "Log in to Mint"
    end

    it "assigns message session to @msg" do
      session[:msg] = "a message"
      get :new
      assigns(:msg).should == "a message"
    end

    it "sets message session to nil" do
      get :new
      session[:msg].should be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

See also: [Rspec: testing assignment of instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720135/rspec-testing-assignment-of-instance-variable)